# Searching functionality working in some pages only

Tags: php, jquery, search

I've header.php file in which I've done coding for searching, search box also is coded in header.php file only.
What I'm doing is if user clicks on Search button it invokes an event & whatever it is written in Search box, same will be taken to search.php file.
Problem is it works pretty fine in index.php & signup.php but doesn't seem to work from any other pages.

```
<script>
$('#searchproductbrand').live('click',function() {
    var search = $('.searchproductbrand').val();
    window.open('search.php?search='+search,'_self');
});
</script>

<input type="search" id="text" class="searchproductbrand" placeholder="Search for Product, Brand" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" autofocus="autofocus" />
<input type="button" id="searchproductbrand" class="button" value="Search" style="padding: 10px 10px;"/>
```

There are no 'searchproductbrand' class & id used anywhere else in any file.
Any suggestions or help?

Comment: May be you have missed to include jquery lib?

Comment: I'm an idiot, how could I forget that thing??:o
Bdw thanks so much, it worked. You should add an answer of this & I will upvote it.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to include **jquery** library in your other pages. Please included into that or add jquery library in common Header page, so that it applies into all the pages wherever you have included the header.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you've included jQuery properly in other pages.

Secondly, try to wrap your code inside DOM ready `$(function() { });` and see:

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchproductbrand').on('click',function() {
        var search = $('.searchproductbrand').val();
        window.open('search.php?search='+search,'_self');
    })
})
```

As well as using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live()` since `live()` is deprecated as of version `1.7`